# Airflow - Change status of failed task to success using CLI

Tags: airflow

I want to change the status of a failed task to success using airflow commands. Is there any way to do that ?

---

I have tried using backfill command, but it is not working for a failed task.

```
airflow backfill -t task_abc_1 -s 2020-05-14T07:11:00.285524+00:00 -e 2020-05-14T07:11:04.862958+00:00 -m dag_abc_1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it. Below command will help to mark a failed task to success. Thanks all for your response.

airflow run -fAIim dag_abc_1 task_abc_1 2020-05-14T07:11:04

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer, but a possible workaround*

---

- Neither [CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref) nor [Rest API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/rest-api-ref.html) seem to offer this
- Nevertheless anything that can be done via UI can be looked up (for *programmatic invocation*) in [`views.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py)

---

So peeking into `views.py` I found that

- [`_mark_task_instance_state(..)` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py#L1285) could help you
- see how they've used it in [`success(..)` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py#L1348)